# Multiple header that can be sorted in datatable.js

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I need headers that can be sorted and work on the server side as in the screenshot. Is it possible to do this with a datatable?

There are multiple headers that don't allow sorting but that's not what I want.[like this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html)

[image]